# How to prevent image to fill entire Tkinter window while resizing?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, tkinter, image-resizing

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24074612/2291710), I wanted to add a second widget below the main image.

The image is intended to fit the window when this one is resized by the user.

See the example from @Marcin:

[image: Resized image]

The issue is that if I add any widget to the window, something weird is happening (here with a Text):

[image: Weird resizing]

The image is growing progressively until it fill the entire window, and the second widget disappears.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO
import base64

root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry("600x600")


class ImageFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *pargs)


        self.black_pixel = BytesIO(base64.b64decode("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs="))
        self.image = Image.open(self.black_pixel)

        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()


        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

        self.width = 1
        self.height = 1

    def _resize_image(self,event):

        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        if new_width != self.width or new_height != self.height:
            self.width = new_width
            self.height = new_height

            self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

            self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
            self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)


img = ImageFrame(root)
txt = Text(root)

img.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
txt.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I tried by packing `img` and `txt` with different options but it chnanged nothing.

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong, please?

Comment: I bet this has something to do with the fact that <Configure> events will fire when anything makes the window resize, not just when the user drags the window handle around. If code inside the callback can change the window size, then it might cause the callback to fire near-continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `.configure` on a widget from within the `<Configure>` callback on same widget is a lot like recursion, there is always a risk of never ending.

When `<Configure>` triggers the `event.width` and `event.height` include the automatic padding of 2 pixels, so setting the image to that size increases the size of the `Label` by 4 pixels firing the `<Configure>` event again.

This doesn't happen in the [example by @markus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061099/tkinter-resize-background-image-to-window-size-python-3-4/24074612#24074612) because once the Label is the size of a window with forced geometry it won't reconfigure again, this is also what happens in your program once the image has finished consuming all the space on the window.

The really quick fix is to change:

```
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height
```

To:

```
    new_width = event.width - 4
    new_height = event.height - 4
```

To compensate for the spacing but I give absolutely no guarantee that it will work consistently.

---

Here is a different implementation that uses a `Canvas` instead of a `Frame` and `Label`:

```
class ImageFrame(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, *pargs ,**kw):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, *pargs,**kw)

        self.black_pixel = BytesIO(base64.b64decode("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs="))
        self.img_copy = Image.open(self.black_pixel)
        self.image = None #this is overriden every time the image is redrawn so there is no need to make it yet

        self.bind("<Configure>",self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):
        origin = (0,0)
        size = (event.width, event.height)
        if self.bbox("bg") != origin + size:
            self.delete("bg")
            self.image = self.img_copy.resize(size)
            self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
            self.create_image(*origin,anchor="nw",image=self.background_image,tags="bg")
            self.tag_lower("bg","all")
```

This way instead of reconfiguring the widget it just redraws the image on the canvas.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much for the explication and the way to solve it!