# Cannot resize list of images on canvas

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I have a rectangle and two images on my canvas. When I resize by dragging window corner down and right this happens:

[image: alpha1.png]

- The blue rectangle resizes properly.
- The red and green images only have their borders resized properly.
- The red and green images stay the same size no matter how I try to regenerate them with `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`.

Here is my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

images = []     # to hold the newly created image
fills = []      # associated list of fill attributes

# a subclass of Canvas for dealing with resizing of windows
class ResizingCanvas(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self,parent,**kwargs)

        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)
        self.height = self.winfo_reqheight()
        self.width = self.winfo_reqwidth()

    def on_resize(self,event):
        # determine the ratio of old width/height to new width/height
        wscale = float(event.width)/self.width
        hscale = float(event.height)/self.height
        # Save new values as old values
        self.width = event.width
        self.height = event.height
        # resize images
        for idx, image in enumerate(images):
            fill=fills[idx]
            dimensions = "image size: %dx%d" % (image.width(), image.height())
            events = "event size: %dx%d" % (event.width, event.height)
            neww=int(image.width()*wscale)
            newh=int(image.height()*hscale)
            image = Image.new('RGBA', (neww, newh), fill)
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
#            images[idx] = image
        # resize the canvas 
        self.config(width=self.width, height=self.height)
        # rescale all objects with the "all" tag
        self.scale("all",0,0,wscale,hscale)

def create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs):
    if 'alpha' in kwargs:
        alpha = int(kwargs.pop('alpha') * 255)
        fill = kwargs.pop('fill')
        fill = root.winfo_rgb(fill) + (alpha,)
        fills.append(fill)
#        print (fill)
        image = Image.new('RGBA', (x2-x1, y2-y1), fill)
        images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))
        mycanvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=images[-1], anchor='nw')
    mycanvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs)

root.title('alpha1.py')

myframe = Frame(root)
myframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
WinWid=1490; WinHgt=860
mycanvas = ResizingCanvas(myframe,width=WinWid, height=WinHgt, \
                          highlightthickness=0)
mycanvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

create_rectangle(100, 100, 600, 600, fill='blue')
create_rectangle(300, 300, 950, 700, fill='green', alpha=.5)
create_rectangle(200, 500, 850, 820, fill='#800000', alpha=.6)
mycanvas.addtag_all("all")

root.mainloop()
```

Notice the line:

```
#            images[idx] = image
```

If I remove the comment `#` then the red and green images aren't painted whatsoever. Only the image borders appear. I think this is the key because `image` should be equal to `images[idx]` prior to resizing.

If you can answer keep in mind the next step in the project will be to grab an image (or rectangle) and move it on the resizable canvas.

Comment: ***"resize ... image on canvas"***: `Canvas.scale` does not resize a image, you have to use, e.g. `new_image = image.resize(...` and `Canvas.itemconfigure(..., image=new_image`.

Comment: @stovfl I was missing the `Canvas.itemconfig(`. Thanks

Comment: @stovfl It's all working now! TYVM. I did have to resort to my own scaling of original width, height because built in .scale(..) method was returning fractional widths, heights between previous and new values. Will you post an answer that I can accept (25 points to you, 2 points to me) or should I post my own? Either way, I wouldn't want this to appear an abandoned question. Closing as a duplicate is also acceptable.

Comment: Feel free to post a community wiki answer, checkbox lower right, to show your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Stovfl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340051/cannot-resize-list-of-images-on-canvas?noredirect=1#comment104883655_59340051) I was able to use:

```
self.itemconfig(items[idx], image=image)
```

To change the size of the image. Unfortunately the way the scaling works in tkinter:

```
# rescale all objects with the "all" tag
self.scale("all",0,0,wscale,hscale)
```

The image wasn't filling the borders completely and missing a pixel or two. So I had to generate my own scaling factor based on original canvas width and height:

```
# images use ratio of original width/height to new width/height
wiscale = float(event.width)/self.startw
hiscale = float(event.height)/self.starth
```

Finally to prevent garbage collector from removing the resized image I assigned it to a list:

```
resized[idx]=image  # stop garbage collector from removing image
```

## TL;DR

Here is the entire Python scrip in case you would like to use it in your own project:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

images = []     # to hold the newly created image
resized = []    # Resized images
fills = []      # associated list of fill attributes
items = []      # associated list of canvass item tags / ids

# a subclass of Canvas for dealing with resizing of windows
class ResizingCanvas(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self,parent,**kwargs)

        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)
        self.height = self.winfo_reqheight()
        self.width = self.winfo_reqwidth()
        self.startw = self.width
        self.starth = self.height

    def on_resize(self,event):
        # determine the ratio of previous width/height to new width/height
        wscale = float(event.width)/self.width
        hscale = float(event.height)/self.height
        # Save new values as old values
        self.width = event.width
        self.height = event.height
        # images use ratio of original width/height to new width/height
        wiscale = float(event.width)/self.startw
        hiscale = float(event.height)/self.starth

        # resize images
        for idx, image in enumerate(images):
            fill=fills[idx]
            neww=int(image.width()*wiscale)
            newh=int(image.height()*hiscale)
            image = Image.new('RGBA', (neww, newh), fill)
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            self.itemconfig(items[idx], image=image)
            resized[idx]=image  # stop garbage collector from removing image

        # resize the canvas 
        self.config(width=self.width, height=self.height)
        # rescale all objects with the "all" tag
        self.scale("all",0,0,wscale,hscale)

def create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs):
    if 'alpha' in kwargs:
        alpha = int(kwargs.pop('alpha') * 255)
        fill = kwargs.pop('fill')
        fill = root.winfo_rgb(fill) + (alpha,)
        fills.append(fill)
        image = Image.new('RGBA', (x2-x1, y2-y1), fill)
        images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))
        item=mycanvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=images[-1], anchor='nw')
        items.append(item)
    mycanvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs)

root.title('alpha1.py')

myframe = Frame(root)
myframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
WinWid=1490; WinHgt=860
mycanvas = ResizingCanvas(myframe,width=WinWid, height=WinHgt, \
                          highlightthickness=0)
mycanvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

create_rectangle(100, 100, 600, 600, fill='blue')
create_rectangle(300, 300, 950, 700, fill='green', alpha=.5)
create_rectangle(200, 500, 850, 820, fill='#800000', alpha=.6)
mycanvas.addtag_all("all")
for image in images:
    resized.append(image)

root.mainloop()
```