# Dynamically resize two panels in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have setup 2 panels in a frame as so:

```
frameA = Frame(master)
frameA.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
frameB = Frame(master)
frameB.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
recale = 0.4
self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.resize((int(rescale*width), int(recale*height)), Image.ANTIALIAS)

self.panelA = Label(frameA, image=self.img)
self.pabelA.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

self.panelB = Label(frameB, image=self.img)
self.pabelB.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

Now, the size of the 2 panels are determined by the image size which I have resized to `0.4` times the original size. How can I dynamically set `rescale` such that the width of each of the panels takes up the entire width of the master frame when I press the maximize button(this is not a button I made, but rather the little square button next to minimize, and close on the top right) on the GUI?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] to illustrate your question?

Comment: if you create `PhotoImage` in function then you have to assign to class variable (ie. `self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)`) because there is bug which removes `PhotoImage` from memory when it is assigned to local variable. See `Note` at the bottom of page [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: you can get screen width `master.winfo_screenwidth()` and set window size `master.geometry('{}x{}'.format(x, y))`

Comment: I've addressed your 1st comment, @furas. For your second comment, how do I use that information to set `rescale` and how do I set this dynamically?

Comment: in question you say nothing about `rescale` but about window size and frame size. It makes difference. You need `window.width` and `bind('<Configure>", on_resize)`

Comment: Yes, but the frame size is being set based on the image size. Hence, in the question I asked "how can I dynamically set this," where this refers to the resize amount.

Comment: @furas I've editted my question to reflect your comment.

Comment: when you use `pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)` then tkinter automatically resize `Frame` and `Label`  to fit window - so you don't have to resize it manually. But it will never resize `PhotoImage` or `Image`. So your real problem probably is "how to resize Image when you change window's size".  There is example [how to resize single image to window's size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061099/tkinter-resize-background-image-to-window-size) but it may need modifiactions for two images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)` then tkinter automatically resizes `Frame` and `Label` to fit window - so you don't have to resize it manually. But it will never resize `PhotoImage` and `Image` so it may looks like it doesn't resize `Label` and `Frame`. So your real problem probably is "how to resize Image when you change window's size"

Using

```
root.bind('<Configure>', on_resize)
```

you can run function when window changed size and then you can generate new image and replace in `Label`

This function will be executed not only for window but also fro every widget in window so I use `str(event.widget) == '.'` to resize it only when it is executed for window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def on_resize(event):
    global rescaled_img
    global photo

    #print('[DEBUG] on_resize:', event.widget)

    # resize only when root window changes size
    if str(event.widget) == '.':
        # generate new image
        width  = event.width//2 # -2  # -2*border
        height = event.height   # -2  # -2*border
        rescaled_img = original_img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rescaled_img)

        # replace images in labels
        label_left['image'] = photo
        label_right['image'] = photo

# ---- main ---

# resize at start
original_img = Image.open('image.jpg')
rescale = 0.4
width = int(rescale * original_img.width)
height = int(rescale * original_img.height)
rescaled_img = original_img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)


root = tk.Tk()

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rescaled_img)

label_left = tk.Label(root, image=photo, border=0) # if border > 0 then you have to use `-2*border` in on_resize
label_left.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

label_right = tk.Label(root, image=photo, border=0) # if border > 0 then you have to use `-2*border` in on_resize
label_right.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

# resize when window changed size
root.bind('<Configure>', on_resize)

root.mainloop()
```

---

I tried to bind to `label` as you can see in some code in [Tkinter resize background image to window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061099/tkinter-resize-background-image-to-window-size) but it didn't work correctly - at start it makes images bigger and bigger till window fill all screen. Or at start it makes images small and small till window has no size.

---

if `Label` has border bigger then 0 then you have to substract `2*border` from image size.