# Adjusting tk windows to photos

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'll preface this with, I am very new to programming. I'm trying to resize my tkinter window "background_app" automatically to any photo that I import into the app. I've seen threads with examples, but they usually create a new class. I'm not at the level of creating a new class yet and I'm wondering if I can do the task without creating a new class. Below is my code with the size currently set to "600x600." Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def main():
    buttons()

def buttons():
    background_app = tk.Tk()
    background_app.title(input("Title? "))
    path = r'C:\Users\Kate\Desktop\Rockphoto.jpg'
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))   #Creates Tkinter photo image
    background_app.geometry("600x600")

    route_image = tk.Label(background_app, image = img) 
    route_image.pack() #Packs widgets in rows or columns

    background_app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just get rid of the `.geometry()` line.  Sizing the window to fit the contents is the default behavior of Tkinter.

Comment: ***resize ... window ... to any photo***: This approach will only work as long the images are not larger then your screen. Does this answer your question? [Tkinter resize background image to window size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24074612/7414759)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Getting rid of the .geometry() worked! I'll try it for a few more images.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PIL to get the image dimensions

Reference here

```
image = PIL.Image.open("sample.png")
```

Get dimensions

```
width, height = image.size
```

Then you can feed this into the geometry.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm struggling with this one. I printed the image.size and it gives me width and height so that works. But when I plug it into geometry is says "bad geometry specifier"